# Use MSAL in Microsoft Teams not work JS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-teams, msal.js

I work on an MS Teams app with a connection to MS Graph.
I'm trying to get an access token for MS Graph in MS Teams. To get a token I'm using MSAL js.

If I run the App with `gulp serve` I receive a valid token and I have access to the MS Graph endpoints. But if I build the app and install it in MS Teams the function `userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(config)` is never executed. I tested it with a console.log before and after the call. There is no error thrown.

Do you have any idea why the above snippet is not executed in MS Teams (app and webapp)?

---

NEW:

**On Home:**

```
export function login() {
  const url = window.location.origin + '/login.html';

  microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: url,
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function(result: string) {
      console.log('Login succeeded: ' + result);
      let data = localStorage.getItem(result) || '';
      localStorage.removeItem(result);

      let tokenResult = JSON.parse(data);
      storeToken(tokenResult.accessToken)
    },
    failureCallback: function(reason) {
      console.log('Login failed: ' + reason);
    }
  });
}
```

**On Login**

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();

    // Get the tab context, and use the information to navigate to Azure AD login page
    microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
      // Generate random state string and store it, so we can verify it in the callback
      let state = _guid();
      localStorage.setItem("simple.state", state);
      localStorage.removeItem("simple.error");

      // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit
      // for documentation on these query parameters
      let queryParams = {
        client_id: "XXX",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        response_mode: "fragment",
        scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid",
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/login-end.html",
        nonce: _guid(),
        state: state,
        login_hint: context.loginHint,
      };

      // Go to the AzureAD authorization endpoint (tenant-specific endpoint, not "common")
      // For guest users, we want an access token for the tenant we are currently in, not the home tenant of the guest. 
      let authorizeEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${context.tid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?` + toQueryString(queryParams);
      window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
    });

    // Build query string from map of query parameter
    function toQueryString(queryParams) {
      let encodedQueryParams = [];
      for (let key in queryParams) {
        encodedQueryParams.push(key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(queryParams[key]));
      }
      return encodedQueryParams.join("&");
    }

    // Converts decimal to hex equivalent
    // (From ADAL.js: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js)
    function _decimalToHex(number) {
      var hex = number.toString(16);
      while (hex.length < 2) {
        hex = '0' + hex;
      }
      return hex;
    }

    // Generates RFC4122 version 4 guid (128 bits)
    // (From ADAL.js: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js)
    function _guid() {...}
```

**on login end**

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
    localStorage.removeItem("simple.error");
    let hashParams = getHashParameters();
    if (hashParams["error"]) {
      // Authentication/authorization failed
      localStorage.setItem("simple.error", JSON.stringify(hashParams));
      microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure(hashParams["error"]);
    } else if (hashParams["access_token"]) {
      // Get the stored state parameter and compare with incoming state
      let expectedState = localStorage.getItem("simple.state");
      if (expectedState !== hashParams["state"]) {
        // State does not match, report error
        localStorage.setItem("simple.error", JSON.stringify(hashParams));
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure("StateDoesNotMatch");
      } else {
        // Success -- return token information to the parent page.
        // Use localStorage to avoid passing the token via notifySuccess; instead we send the item key.
        let key = "simple.result";
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({
          idToken: hashParams["id_token"],
          accessToken: hashParams["access_token"],
          tokenType: hashParams["token_type"],
          expiresIn: hashParams["expires_in"]
        }));
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess(key);
      }
    } else {
      // Unexpected condition: hash does not contain error or access_token parameter
      localStorage.setItem("simple.error", JSON.stringify(hashParams));
      microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure("UnexpectedFailure");
    }
    // Parse hash parameters into key-value pairs
    function getHashParameters() {
      let hashParams = {};
      location.hash.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function (item) {
        let s = item.split("="),
          k = s[0],
          v = s[1] && decodeURIComponent(s[1]);
        hashParams[k] = v;
      });
      return hashParams;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Bot or Tab? Here is the documentation on [Authentication in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication). Here is the a nice video on authentication in [Microsoft Teams](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2018/THR5023).

Comment: I Use Tab. Thanks for your response

Comment: Now `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` works fine, but only in the Browser Teams app. In the Native App the Login Popup is opend as a standard Browsertab and nothing happens then. @Wajeed-MSFT

Comment: Could you please try [Teams Authentication Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node) once to see the authentication flow experience? Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Also, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-flow-tab, particularly step 3. Did you register a successCallback() function, and if so, is it being called?

Comment: I posted my code above...
I am a little bit confused that the flow works in the Webapp but not in the nativ App.
@BillBliss-MSFT I think i registered the successCallback. Please have a look at the code above.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though my answer is quite late, but I faced the same problem recently.

The solution is farely simple: MSALs silent login does not work in MSTeams (yet) as MSTeams relies on an IFrame Approach that is not supported by MSAL.

You can read all about it in [this Github Issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/899)

Fortunately, they are about to release a fix for this in Version `msal 1.2.0` and there is already an npm-installable beta which should make this work:

`npm install msal@1.2.0-beta.2`

**Update**: I tried this myself - and the beta does not work as well. This was confirmed by Microsoft in my own [Github Issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1095).

So I guess at the time being, you simply can't use MSAL for MS Teams.